# Heroku Python Remote Rejected error

Tags: python, git, heroku, deployment

I am making a Simple Python Bot which can be run like `python file.py` . I created a Folder in my PC having 3 files `file.py list.txt Procfile` . In Procfile i wrote `worker: python file.py` , I choosed worker as it a Command Line application and my plan is to run that Python File forever on the server. Than i did `git init` , `heroku git:remote -a py-bot-xyz` where py-bot-xyz is the application which i created in My Heroku Dashboard and than `git add .`, `git commit -am "make it better"` & finally `git push heroku master` .

That's where the error occurs, that prints out

```
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote: 
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
    remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
    remote:       to use for this application automatically.
    remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
    remote: 
    remote: Verifying deploy....
    remote: 
    remote: !   Push rejected to py-bot-xyz.
    remote: 
    To https://git.heroku.com/py-bot-xyz.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/py-bot-xyz.git'
```

Now, when i go to Heroku's Dashboard Build Failed in Activity. What can i do now? :(((

Answer (score 2):

To successfully push python code to heroku you should have a requirements.txt and a Procfile. Go to your project folder in terminal/commandline and enter the following commands which will generate the necessary files. Commit them and push should work.

1. `pip freeze > requirements.txt`(you might need to install pip, if using older python version)
2. `echo "worker: python yourfile.py" > Procfile` (`worker` could be replaced with `web` if it's a website)

Answer (score 1):

Each Heroku buildpack applies different tests to determine if it applies. For Python, the buildpack looks for a 'requirements.txt' or 'setup.py' file (see https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/detect). If you don't have one of those files, you can set it explicitly via `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python`. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#setting-a-buildpack-on-an-application

Comment: ... or a 'Pipfile'

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same kind of error. As I am new to this area..
I used "requirement.txt" instead of "requirements.txt".

Watch out for the exact spellings.