# App not compatible with buildpack - Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

When I run `git push heroku master` this is what I get:

```
C:\Users\Emanuele-PC\Desktop\project-mm-beta>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 505 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to project-mm-beta.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/project-mm-beta.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/project-mm-beta.git'
```

The code I am trying to deploy is just one file (it's a test because it's my first time using Heroku) and it's written in Python. I have already set the buildpack (python) but it still doesn't work. How can I solve?

Comment: You need to include a `requirements.txt` file. It can be empty. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#activation-1

Comment: I did but I still get that error.

Comment: Are any other errors shown if you run `heroku logs`

Comment: There is only this error: `2017-09-08T06:18:27.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs` repeating at different times (only this type of error, no other one). But I think it's related to "App not compatible with buildpack".

Comment: Maybe add a Procfile like https://stackoverflow.com/a/44854965/6085135

Comment: Done but I still get that error, I don't know...

Comment: Solved. I created a new app and I followed all the steps again (the previous one has US as country when I am in EU, I don't know if that could have been one of the reason. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Glad it's working, if it happens again maybe `git push -f heroku master` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794413/failed-to-push-some-refs-to-githeroku-com

Comment: Make sure that your buildpack is set correctly check out the docs for heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#officially-supported-buildpacks

Comment: I totally got same error when my branch `master` on github does not have any files (ex. package.json ...), so when i typed `git push heroku master`, it did not detect any files for building and pushing them (ex. can not find package.json). Therefore, after i pushed files to github, and typed `git push heroku master` success for release.

Comment: after you do pip freeze>requirements.txt, don't forget to git add . and git commit -m "added requirements.txt". Only then try again with git push heroku master

Answer (score 59):

The Heroku Python Support will be applied to applications only when the application has a `Pipfile`, `setup.py`, or `requirements.txt` in the root directory.

Visit the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support) to get detailed instructions.

Answer (score 34):

I just found out... It's quite a silly issue. Make sure the git repo is initialized within the project root folder. Suppose the project is a Django app and the project folder created by Django is `my-project`, the git repo needs to be initialized right within `my-project` for Heroku to work...

Comment: What do you mean by repo needs to be 'initialized' within the root. I know where the root is, but not what you mean by initializing a git repo within a particular folder.

Comment: I meant project root folder. I explained with a `my-project` example as well.

Comment: i am building flask applicatoin and didn't work for me

Comment: same happened to me

Comment: This is what fixed my version of this issue, very good answer. Upvoted

Answer (score 16):

Add `Pipfile` and `Procfile`, and **commit** them. This solved it for me.

You can see the files I am speaking of on [this Heroku documentation](https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started).

And here is a link to Heroku's [Python buildpack on GitHub](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python).

Comment: *slaps forehead* Forgot to commit, lost half an hour.

Answer (score 8):

You can try doing:

1. `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt`
2. `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python`
3. `git add .; git commit -m "add requirements.txt"; git push heroku master`

Note: Make sure you're in your root directory of your Python project :)

Answer (score 4):

try add a file named requirement.txt
and enter anything you need like django

Comment: The OP noted in the comments that this error persists ever when a `requirements.txt` file is present.

Answer (score 3):

> Step 1) First setup the buildpack (programming-language )

For example : **`heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs`**

Check for more info here : *https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks*

*If the issue still exists, then follow next step*

> Step 2) git init and currently used directory is
>   ***different***, so this error is still thrown **"App not compatible with buildpack:"**

For example : **`git init`** command was used executed at :- ***C:/sample_folder/***

But **modules and package.json** is under **nested** sub-folder :-

***C:/sample_folder/nodejs_app/package.json***

> So move the files accordingly such that all the file are **present under the same folder**
>   and then run

`git push heroku master`

--happy coding!

Comment: This is extremely helpful; this was the only post which contained the stuff about "you have to make sure you're git is in the right spot." +1.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error because I was making changes to a different branch. So I was working of a feature branch, then running `git push heroku master`. My changes had not been merged into my master branch, so thus the error. Once I merged in the Procfile to master I was able to push the changes up to heroku.

Answer (score 2):

**First file:** `requirements.txt`

containing something like: `gunicorn==19.7.1` or whatever the results of `pip freeze > requirements.txt` are.

**Second file:** `Procfile`

containing something like: `web: gunicorn app:app` or potentially blank. Note that `app:app` in this example is a reference to your python filename. It means that every time a web process is declared, and a dyno of this type is started, also run the command `gunicorn app:app` to start your web server.

Then `git add .` and `git commit -m "added Procfile and requirements.txt"`.

Then run `git push heroku master` to push from your `local master` branch to the `heroku remote`.

Comment: It's great that you have answered the question, but can you please explain it more clearly? One way of making this more clearer is by formatting things as code. You can do this by using backticks `\``

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same error because I was not committing the files, make sure you run the command `git add .` then `git commit -m'message'` after changing any file, and then you can `run git push heroku master` and also add the `requirements.txt` and `Procfile` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Just make sure that you initialized the git repo inside the django project root. That way, your .git folder, .gitignore file, manage.py, requirements.txt, etc.. are on the same hierarchical level.

Comment: This solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the buildpack for python by this method

**CLI Installation**

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally make sure you're not ignoring `requirements.txt` from your .gitignore, That was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

-> Make sure your requirements.txt & Procfile are in the root folder.

-> run following commands if you are not in the master branch already.

```
git checkout -b master
git add .
git commit -m "your commit message"
git push -u origin master
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you did the following steps:

1. Activate your virtual environment.
2. Run on your command prompt:
   `pip freeze>requirements.txt`
3. Add `Procfile` in your main app directory (the same where `manage.py` is);
    inside Procfile you should insert:
   `web: gunicorn your_app_name.wsgi`

Comment: Oops, you misspelled the `requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Well, same happened to me while I was creating a first-time **Heroku** app.
Just add `requirements.txt`. It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed README.md from my GitHub repository which was connected to my Heroku app, and that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have written correct spelling of Procfile and requirements.txt, because they are case sensitive and In my case after changing the procfile to Procfile it started working properly.

Answer (score -2):

Run this command:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```

Also you can refer [this](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python) document.

Comment: This just says: `The buildpack heroku/python is already set on your app.`