# Flask application deployment to heroku, not compatible with buildpack

Tags: python, heroku

I have made a flask application that I want to deploy to Heroku for testing purposes.

I have created the app and everything, but whenever I run the command:

```
git push heroku master.
```

I get the following error.

```
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpa
cks/heroku/python.tgz
```

since it is a flask application, I do not understand, why it is wrong that I set the buildpack to python.

(I'm using python 2.7)

In my Procfile I have added the following line:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

In my requirements.txt I have specified all the dependencies:

```
Flask==0.12
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Flask-Mail==0.9.0
Flask-MySQLdb==0.2.0
Flask-ReCaptcha==0.4.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
gunicorn==19.7.1
Jinja2==2.8.1
```

along with some more dependencies I used the 
    pip freeze > requirements.txt 
command to get the file, so all should be included

Comment: Have a look at the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109465/app-not-compatible-with-buildpack-heroku). There is no accepted answer, but maybe one of the suggestions works for you.