# Error pushing nodejs(express) app to heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I'm trying to push my nodejs(express) app to heroku using `heroku push master`.

I keep getting the following error:

```
App not compatible with buildpack:
https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/nodejs.tgz
```

Comment: Ok from research, i see that the app must have a package.json file and a readme.md file before i can push to heroku (i mean for a nodejs app like mine). But, heck i do!!!. or i thought i did. apparently i have all my work on branches because i have kept my code base(master) clean hence i don't have a package.json file. what do i do now, pls help!!!

Comment: what have you tried so far? Can you post a [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App not compatible with buildpack - Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109465/app-not-compatible-with-buildpack-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

when I participated at Node Knockout last year, I ran into the same problem.
Turned out I forgot to add a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#setting-a-buildpack-on-an-application).

Do you have one? If so, could you share its content?