# Error in deploying Python app, "app not compatible with buildpack"

Tags: python, flask, heroku

[image: Image For Your Reference]

I got an error while deploying my Python app in Heroku, I already have requirnments.txt, runtime.txt, Procfile, I already added buildpack(heroku/python) in setting, but I got error i.e "app not compatible with buildpack".

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your directory structure. In particular, please identify the locations of your `.git/` folder (the root directory of your project) and your `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you initialized the git repo initialized in the project root directory? Also, are you using Django?

There is a very similar question posted asking this same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109465/app-not-compatible-with-buildpack-heroku). The user received the same error message, `app not compatible with buildpack.` This problem was fixed by initializing the repository in the root directory (root directory: `git init`).

I'm also posting another link [here](https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started). This is an example python app deployed to heroku. Please note the CLI commands as well to be sure there aren't any problems there for you.

Comment: damn, great call!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the git repo is initialized within the project root folder. If the project folder is `my-project`, you need to initialize git inside the folder for heroku to work.