# Heroku build loops forever for node server with nested react/webpack client on it's own github repo

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack, package.json

I'm trying to run a server on heroku that has a directory that looks something like

```
my-app
    server.js
    package.json
    client
        src
        dist
        package.json
```

The nested `package.json` has a `scripts` section that contains

```js
      "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
        "build": "webpack --mode production"
      },
```

The outer `package.json` has a scripts section like this

```js
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node server",
        "build": "cd client/ && npm install && npm run build"
      },
```

When I push my project to heroku, I receive this output, and it just loops forever

```js
     Build
    remote:        Running build
    remote:        
    remote:        > my-app@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_myapp
    remote:        > cd client/ && npm install && npm run build
    remote:
    remote:        audited 259 packages in 2.495s
    remote:        
    remote:        3 packages are looking for funding
    remote:          run `npm fund` for details
    remote:
    remote:        found 1 low severity vulnerability
    remote:          run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
    remote:        
    remote:        > my-app@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_myapp
    remote:        > cd client/ && npm install && npm run build
    remote:
    remote:        audited 259 packages in 2.252s
    remote:        
    remote:        3 packages are looking for funding
    remote:          run `npm fund` for details
    remote:
    remote:        found 1 low severity vulnerability
    remote:          run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
    remote:        
    remote:        > my-app@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_myapp
    remote:        > cd client/ && npm install && npm run build
    remote:
    remote:        audited 259 packages in 2.238s
    remote:        
    remote:        3 packages are looking for funding
    remote:          run `npm fund` for details
```

---

I have a node server on a github repo. One of the folders within this repo is a client folder, which has it's own github repo. I push everything to heroku using `git push heroku master` from within the server folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely because build command is running itself again and again, you can fix this by changing name of the outer script to something other than build, let's say `buildClient`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "buildClient": "cd client/ && npm install && npm run build"
},
```

and run `npm run-script buildClient` instead of `npm build`.

Not sure if you can run custom script on heroku or not, but you should be able to rename script from `build` to [`heroku-postbuild`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1573) and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting a different error now `App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/kreativgebiet/heroku-buildpack-webpack ... ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to ...`. [I've read that it could have something to do with a requirements.txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109465/app-not-compatible-with-buildpack-heroku). I added an empty `requirements.txt` file, but am still getting the same error. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Sam do you have `index.js` file in your source? May be you can share your log in pastebin.

Comment: No I don't, I named it `server.js` cause I thought it was more clear. I'll change it and see what happens

Comment: Also, one more thing your plugin is also checking for `webpack.config.js` in the root directory https://github.com/kreativgebiet/heroku-buildpack-webpack/blob/master/bin/detect

Comment: Webpack exists in a sub directory, I have a setup with a server in the root directory which is a node server, and a folder called `client` within the root folder. The client folder has a `webpack.config.js`, it's own git repo and is another project.

Comment: There was no change after switching `server.js` to `index.js`. I updated my `package.json` scripts section to have `"start": "node index.js",` and my Procfile to be `web: node index.js` also

Comment: @Sam I haven't used buildpack with multi application setup so unless I can check config files and run it, mostly I will be shooting in the dark. Did you try it using: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi-procfile?

Comment: So I have a single heroku app, which serves my front end from one of it's ports, but 2 github repos, one for the server and one for the client. It's the opposite scenario of what's described in the link from your last comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223472/discussion-between-dipen-shah-and-sam).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use Procfile like this.

```
web: npm run start
```

The outer package.json is like this.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node server",
  "heroku-postbuild": "cd client/ && npm install && npm run build"
},
```

---

If that doesn't work, check out this article.
[How to deploy multiple apps in a monorepo with Heroku](https://medium.com/inato/how-to-setup-heroku-with-yarn-workspaces-d8eac0db0256)

This article mentions multiple apps on heroku, which should be helpful

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting a different error now `App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/kreativgebiet/heroku-buildpack-webpack ... ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to ...`. [I've read that it could have something to do with a requirements.txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109465/app-not-compatible-with-buildpack-heroku). I added an empty `requirements.txt` file, but am still getting the same error. Do you know how to fix this?