# python/django can't deploy to heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

i get this error when i try to deploy my project on heroku

i have followed a tutorial for proshop for him it worked fine without any issues but i get this error below

```
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python

-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz

       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure

 !     Push failed
```

i already tried some of the mentioned stuff like heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python and have requirments.txt and procfile in my project

Comment: Make sure you've also actually committed those files. Additionally, take a look at this to make sure you're in the correct dir: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51121582

Comment: yes everything commited and dir: is correct aswell :/

Comment: And is your python version (in runtime.txt) exactly the same as the one specified in heroku's list? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#specifying-a-python-version

Comment: You say you have a file called `requirments.txt`, but that's not the correct name for that file. It must be `requirements.txt`, with an `e` after the second `r`.

Comment: Chris that was exactly the issue i feel so stupid wasting 2 days on that