# App not compatible with buildpack , django heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

Using buildpack: heroku/python but still it says not compatible
Please Help i am a beginner in django

Here is build log :

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

And here is the project :https://github.com/Shadow-Knight503/Meme_Site

Comment: Hello @Shdow_Knight your project url is invalid or maybe it moved and about this error it can be caused because of invalid name of **requirements.txt** or if your forgot to put it check this answer for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/51931233/14457833

Answer (score 0):

In the root of your project rename `requirements` to `requirements.txt`.

This is a necessary to ensure Heroku can [recognize a Python application](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#recognizing-a-python-app).