# Django: App not compatible with buildpack

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Django app on Heroku and I am getting this error -

[image: error]

Based on the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109465/app-not-compatible-with-buildpack-heroku?newreg=30cf2eba5f86481995689112ef88e6b9) question, here is what I have tried so far -

1. Adding the `requirements.txt` file in the root directory of the project.
2. Adding `Procfile` in the root directory of my project.
3. Made sure git is initialized in the root directory of my project.

This is what my project structure looks like -

[image: Project Structure]

This is what my `Procfile` looks like -

```
web: gunicorn GameStudio.wsgi --log-file -
```

Any suggestions/pointers will be highly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: as far as I can remember, Heroku stops SQLite deployments. [ref](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3)

Comment: Tried deleting db.sqlite3 file and pushing again, got same error

Comment: "App not compatible with buildpack" has nothing to do with your `Procfile`, or with use of SQLite (though shivankgtm and Prachi Jain are correct that it doesn't work properly on Heroku). It's purely about `requirements.txt` (or `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` if you're using Pipenv). Is the `requirements.txt` file committed?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Noted. Yes, requiements.txt is committed.

Comment: Well Heroku doesn't seem to think so. Are you absolutely sure? What does `git ls-files requirements.txt` output? Is it committed to your `master` branch, or another branch? Are you able to share a link to the repository?

Comment: Sure @Chris ! Here is the repo [link](https://github.com/Prachi-Jain01/GameStudio). The code is on master branch. `git ls-files requirements.txt` doesn't return anything.

Comment: "`git ls-files requirements.txt` doesn't return anything"—then you _don't_ have a committed file called `requirements.txt`. Looking at your repository, I see `Requirements.txt` but that's different from `requirements.txt`. I'll point you to another question that answers how to fix this.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris !! Now the git ls-files requirements.txt command returns "requirements.txt" and I have moved to further steps. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Glad to help, @PrachiJain. Take care.